# unknown Exception android

Tags: android

This is my main file, which has image buttons, and it gives me an exception. When I click on courses image button, it just closes the application.

It works for rest of buttons (rest activities just consist a text view and button) whereas in courses view, I added 3 more buttons (before I added these 3 buttons, it used to work for switching between main and courses).

What i am trying to do is this:

Make 3 buttons in courses activity. They will navigate me to other views like "higher education" or "further education". In next views I will create a list which will display name of courses (like "CCNA" or "Health diploma"!). When the user clicks on course, it will display a picture and some text information about the course.

```
package com.NVT.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Main extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ImageButton CoursesButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.CoursesButton);
        ImageButton ILoveNescotButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ILoveNescotButton);
        ImageButton CampusMapButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.CampusMapButton);
        ImageButton GettingHereButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.GettingHereButton);

        CoursesButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Courses.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });

        ILoveNescotButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ILoveNescot.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });

        CampusMapButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CampusMap.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });

        GettingHereButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), GettingHere.class);
                            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Code for Courses View  "Courses.java" is given below,,,,

```
package com.NVT.android;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class Courses extends Activity 
    {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.courses);


            Button ButtonFurtherEducation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Courses_FurtherEducation);
            Button ButtonHigherEducation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Courses_HigherEducation);
            Button ButtonEmployernTraining = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button_Courses_EmployersnTraining);
            Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);


            ButtonFurtherEducation.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FurtherEducationCourses.class);
                                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            });


            ButtonHigherEducation.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HigherEducationCourses.class);
                                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            });

            ButtonEmployernTraining.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EmployersTrainingCourses.class);
                                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
                }

            });



            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }

            });
        }   
    }
```

and code for the   further Education Activity is given below,,,,

```
package com.NVT.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class FurtherEducationCourses extends Activity 
    {

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.further_education);

            Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View view) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
                }

            });
        }   
    }
```

my Manifest coding as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.NVT.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".Courses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CampusMap">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".GettingHere">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ILoveNescot">
        </activity>


        <activity android:name=".FurtherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".HigherEducationCourses">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmployersTrainingCourses">
        </activity>







    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: You may also add the exception you are getting.

Comment: it just closes the application, when i click on courses button as i said "Force close" or something...

Comment: i think problem starts from " Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Courses.class);"

Comment: Sounds like the classic problem where you have not specified the new activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: i think i added all the activities required and as show above i added the coding of manifest file

Comment: all activities have been added as far as i can think

Comment: @Tom Long: the correct number of punctuation characters at each point is 1. A single full stop or comma is enough (unless you want to write an ellipsis, which should only be used on incomplete sentences).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: Can you please Explain what you said, as i didn;t got anything at all from that :S

Comment: @Tom: Will you please give the logcat outout when the force close occur from DDMS. Then may be we will be able to find the error easily.

Comment: @Tom: Don't use "...." or ",,,," as punctuation. It looks terrible and gives the impression that you don't care about things like syntax. That would be a bad trait for a programmer.

Comment: @gypsicoder: i uploaded screenshot of logcat here (http://i53.tinypic.com/2nsujgl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will see in the logcat screen that the first line with class name from your application is 'Courses.java'. So, the error occurs there. In the logcat you will see NullPointerException at Courses.java line 63. In line 63 of Courses.java you have set the onclick listener for the next button. So, I think the next button stay null when this line executes. I think the main error is in line no 21

```
Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
```

I think the id of the next button in the layout file (corses.xml) is not Button01. Please fix this thing then there will be no errors.

Just try it. :)

Comment: yeah that was the problem, i am able to course view, but now not going forward to Further Education window, please guide if you can, thanks alot gypsicoder :D

Comment: Does it show same error as for the Courses.java? In the furthereducation you have used the same code as for the courses.java for the next button. If that's ok then is the problem when you click the next button? Then, I think the problem is here: Intent intent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                    finish();
Use the following codes instead of the above codes: setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();

Comment: it was same button01 problem in furthereducation.xml file, thanks alot for your time, i will be back if need more help, thanks, i am going to ask a new question regarding tab activity in android, thanks again :)

Comment: then please up vote my answer and if the answer is correct then mark the answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: how can i do that, please guide

Comment: not got enough reputation to vote up but both answers are correct but i understood gypsicoder more, soo selected it

Answer (score 1):

According to the logcat screenshot, your problem is that Button next is null, since it is a `NullPointerException` in line 63, which is when you call `next.setOnClickListener`, which means that `R.id.Button01` is not in `R.layout.courses`, could you verify if this information is correct?

Comment: am really sorry, but i didn;t get that, i went into R.java file and i looked into " public static final class id " and found this "public static final int Button01=0x7f050002;" so i think its there, please guide

Comment: you have a file called courses that is a layout, in it, you have the buttons Button_Courses_FurtherEducation, Button_Courses_HigherEducation, Button_Courses_EmployersnTraining; nut it seems that Button01 is not declared in that file; thus returing null when using findViewById(R.id.Button01); so either you have it named differently or you haven't added to the file.
Let me know what you found