# Tabactivity android Vs Iphone

Tags: android

hi i just fixed the issue i had with
 my application, now i am stuck with
 another problem, please help :)

most of my code is here

"[unknown Exception android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991635/unknown-exception-android)"

now i want to make my main page look like this as shown in iphone
 application given below,

"http://wwwm.coventry.ac.uk/app/Pages/iPhoneApp.aspx"

i dont know if i need to use   tab activity or option menu or inflator,

as for call, email and web, i will have to call services as far as i
 know.

and last if i can see any tutorial or code which will help me to solve my
 problem, please give me a link.

thanks alot**

```
Main.xml looks like this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<AbsoluteLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/AbsoluteLayout01">


<TextView android:layout_x="61dip" android:layout_y="176dip" android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/courses"></TextView>



<ImageButton android:id="@+id/CoursesButton" android:layout_x="62dip" android:layout_y="107dip" android:background="@drawable/a" android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_width="65dp"></ImageButton>



<TextView android:gravity="center" android:textSize="25dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/LabelNescot" android:layout_x="1dip" android:layout_y="39dip" android:id="@+id/TextView"></TextView>

<ImageButton android:id="@+id/ILoveNescotButton" android:background="@drawable/b" android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_width="65dp" android:layout_x="179dip" android:layout_y="106dip"></ImageButton>
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/GettingHereButton" android:background="@drawable/d" android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_width="65dp" android:layout_x="185dip" android:layout_y="208dip"></ImageButton>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/Directions" android:layout_x="182dip" android:layout_y="283dip"></TextView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/facility" android:layout_x="180dip" android:layout_y="177dip"></TextView>



<ImageButton android:background="@drawable/c" android:id="@+id/CampusMapButton" android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_width="65dp" android:layout_x="48dip" android:layout_y="208dip"></ImageButton>
<TextView android:text="@string/Map" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_x="37dip" android:layout_y="285dip"></TextView>

</AbsoluteLayout>






z
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hello Tab Layout](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Comment: tried that already, buh i dont want a frame layout to be used, and as its 3 buttons, Call, Email or Web, if users clicks a button, it will call the service not the view ! soo please justify if u want me to use hello tab layout or any tutorial as i am begginnr :) ! thanks for your time !

Comment: You need to rewrite your question with the relevant details then.  It is very vague as to what you are trying to accomplish. You say you want your app to look like that in the linked picture, the obvious thing is to use a tab layout. Why don't you want to use a frame layout?

Comment: i want to show the three buttons , call, email and web on the bottom of my screen like its in the screen, but if i use tab layout, i have to use frame layout, whereas for me frame means a view, but as i actually used the iphone app and when i click on the call, it opens up a dialog box and if i click yes, it closes the application and starting calling a number !,

Comment: sooo basically all i want is three image buttons that will be calling different services, not the views, like in tab lay out if you click the artist tab (given example) it takes you to the artist activity view using frame layout, as far as i know !, but if am wrong please help !

Comment: If all you want is three buttons, just use a horizontal `LinearLayout`.  The different layouts are covered in great detail in the Android developer docs.  Read through those to get started.  Definitely do not use an `AbsoluteLayout`, as you have in your example.  That is deprecated. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: thanks for your time Mayra :), am not trying to be rude, but i think you need to look at the main screen of that iphone application again, as it clearly states what i need, which cant be simply done using, tab activity, neither using buttons or inflator or menu option, unless i make huge changes in them, need a bit more precise guide !

Comment: Sorry Tom, I don't have time to write your application for you.  If you put together an attempt (not using AbsoluteLayouts) based on the extensive documentation, and point out what exactly the problem is that isn't solved by your attempt, someone might be able to help you solve that particular problem.

Comment: i wonder whats wrong with absolute layout ?, they are soo easy 2 use ! and working fine at the moment, well i did made an attempt and i gonna put that code in my question up there, and i am not asking you to write my application ! i am just asking for guidance !

Comment: Absolute layouts are deprecated.  You can probably get it to work fine in the emulator, or on one phone, but as soon as you try to use it on a phone with a different resolution, or pixel density it will all stop working.  See supporting multiple screens for details:http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  I still have absolutely no idea what exactly your problem is, other than "tell me how to duplicate this screen".  If you are perfectly happy with your sample layout, then whats the problem?

Comment: hmmm you are right about Absolute layouts, but i already used them in my application, and is there anyway i can change it to linear or frame layout ?

Comment: my problem is, i dont know which approach should i use for that three buttons to be used in my layout at bottom, and work for services, thats the best i can explain atm, or we can chat somewhere else, so i can explain it better, like yahoo or msn or skype ?

Comment: btw i used linear layout and then filled it with absolute layout, do think it still be a issue while working with different phones ! thanks

Comment: It should not be hard to recreate your layouts without using absolute layouts, just read through all of those tutorials I linked.  Or, you can check out one of the wysiwyg editors like the one in Eclipse, or Droid Draw.  How you layout your buttons has absolutely nothing to do with what happens when you click on them.  Just use a LinearLayout to lay them out, then add onClick listeners that invoke the services.